# How to limit a UIWindowScene to create only one window?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiwindowscene

One of my apps uses two `UIWindowScene` configurations. One of these two configurations is the main view of the app. I want to limit the number of windows for the main view to just one. So essentially I want a classic 'one main window' and 'multiple sub windows' architecture.

This all results in the following question: *Is it possible to prevent the creation of a new `UIWindowScene` if one has already been created with the same configuration?*

Comment: Are you basically looking for a way to prevent a user from using the "New Window" feature of multitasking on an iPad?

Comment: @HangarRash Yes, but only for the main window.

Comment: I have no idea if this will work but try implementing the `application(_:configurationForConnecting:options:)` UIApplicationDelegate method and for the main window, return an empty configuration. Maybe that will prevent the window.